# OnClickListener of TextView not responding in slider

Tags: android, onclick, slider, textview, onclicklistener

How to execute TextView onclick . my java code is :

Introduction.java :

```
public class Introduction extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
ImageView menubutton;
TextView intro;
TextView menutext1;
TextView menutext2;
TextView menutext3;
TextView menutext4;
TextView menutext5;
TextView menutext6;
TextView menutext7;
TextView menutext8;
RelativeLayout menupanel;
ScrollView description;
Boolean move = false;
TextView tv1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.introduction);

    menubutton=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.menuViewButton);
    menutext1=(TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.menu_item_1);
    menutext2=(TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.menu_item_2);
    menutext3=(TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.menu_item_3);
    menutext4=(TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.menu_item_4);
    menutext5=(TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.menu_item_5);
    menutext6=(TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.menu_item_6);
    menutext7=(TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.menu_item_7);
    menutext8=(TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.menu_item_8);
    menutext1.setOnClickListener(this);
    menupanel=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.menuPanel);
    description=(ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.descriptionScrollView);
    intro=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.intro);
        tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        menutext1.setOnClickListener(this);
        menutext2.setOnClickListener(this);
        menutext3.setOnClickListener(this);
        menutext4.setOnClickListener(this);
        menutext5.setOnClickListener(this);
        menutext6.setOnClickListener(this);
        menutext7.setOnClickListener(this);
        menutext8.setOnClickListener(this);

        menutext1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            move = false;
            Animation slideright= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.right_to_left);
            Animation slide= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.movingright_to_left);
            menupanel.startAnimation(slideright);
            description.startAnimation(slide);
            intro.setText("Introduction");
        }
    });

    menutext2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            move = false;
            Animation slideright= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.right_to_left);
            Animation slide= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.movingright_to_left);
            menupanel.startAnimation(slideright);
            description.startAnimation(slide);
            intro.setText("Preface");
            Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Inside preface", 1);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL,0, 130);
            toast.show();

            tv1.setText("This is the third pocket size edition of the Constitution of India in the diglot form. In this edition, the text of the Constitution of India has been brought up-to-date by incorporating therein all the amendments up to and including the Constitution (Ninety-Sixth Amendment) Act, 2011.  \n\n 2. The Constitution applies to the State of Jammu and Kashmir with certain exceptions and modifications as provided in article 370 and the Constitution (Application to Jammu and Kashmir) Order, 1954. This Order has been included in Appendix I for facility of reference.  Appendix II contains a re-statement of the exceptions and modifications.  The text of the constitutional amendments relating to the Constitution (Forty-fourth Amendment) Act, 1978 and Constitution (Eighty-eighth Amendment) Act, 2003, which have not come in force, have been provided in Appendix  III and IV respectively. ");
        }
    });

    menutext3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            move = false;
            Animation slideright= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.right_to_left);
            Animation slide= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.movingright_to_left);
            menupanel.startAnimation(slideright);
            description.startAnimation(slide);
            intro.setText("Preamble");
        }
    });

    menutext4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            move = false;
            Animation slideright= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.right_to_left);
            Animation slide= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.movingright_to_left);
            menupanel.startAnimation(slideright);
            description.startAnimation(slide);
            intro.setText("Index");
        }
    });

    menutext5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            move = false;
            Animation slideright= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.right_to_left);
            Animation slide= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.movingright_to_left);
            menupanel.startAnimation(slideright);
            description.startAnimation(slide);
            intro.setText("Articles");
        }
    });

    menutext6.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            move = false;
            Animation slideright= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.right_to_left);
            Animation slide= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.movingright_to_left);
            menupanel.startAnimation(slideright);
            description.startAnimation(slide);
            intro.setText("Schedules");
        }
    });

    menutext7.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            move = false;
            Animation slideright= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.right_to_left);
            Animation slide= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.movingright_to_left);
            menupanel.startAnimation(slideright);
            description.startAnimation(slide);
            intro.setText("Appendix");
        }
    });

    menutext8.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            move = false;
            Animation slideright= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.right_to_left);
            Animation slide= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.movingright_to_left);
            menupanel.startAnimation(slideright);
            description.startAnimation(slide);
            intro.setText("Amendment");
        }
    });


    menubutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(!move)
    {
        move = true;

        Animation slideleft= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.move);
        Animation slide= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.moving);
        menupanel.startAnimation(slideleft);
    //  introduction.startAnimation(slide);
    }

else{
        move = false;
        Animation slideright= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.right_to_left);
        Animation slide= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.movingright_to_left);
        menupanel.startAnimation(slideright);
        //introduction.startAnimation(slide);

}
}
});


}

public void preface()
{


            move = false;
            Animation slideright= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.right_to_left);
            Animation slide= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.movingright_to_left);
            menupanel.startAnimation(slideright);
            description.startAnimation(slide);
            intro.setText("Preface");
            Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Inside preface", 1);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL,0, 130);
            toast.show();

            tv1.setText("This is the third pocket size edition ");
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



}
```

introduction.xml code :-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Introduction" >

   <!-- Sliding Panel -->     
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/slidingPanel"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@android:color/white" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/blue_bg" >

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/header_vertical_divider_1"
                    android:layout_width="2dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/menuViewButton"
                    android:background="@drawable/engraved_bg" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/menuViewButton"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/description"
                        android:src="@drawable/icon_menu"
                        android:visibility="visible" />
                                    </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                 android:id="@+id/dividerHeaderBottom"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="1dp"
                 android:background="#414141" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/intro"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="#d3d3d3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="CONSTITUTION OF INDIA"
                android:textSize="16dp" />

   <ScrollView
       android:id="@+id/menu"
       android:layout_width="137dp"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
       android:scrollbars="none" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/menuPanel"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/gray_bg"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="invisible" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/menu_item_1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"             
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="@string/item_1"
            android:clickable="true">     
        </TextView>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/menu_item_divider_1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/menu_item_1"
            android:background="#b5b5b5"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/menu_item_2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"             
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_below="@+id/menu_item_divider_1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="@string/item_2">     
        </TextView>     
         <View
            android:id="@+id/menu_item_divider_2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/menu_item_2"
            android:background="#b5b5b5"/> 
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/menu_item_3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/menu_item_divider_2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="@string/item_3"
            android:clickable="true">
        </TextView>
        <View
            android:id="@+id/menu_item_divider_3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/menu_item_3"
            android:background="#b5b5b5" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/menu_item_4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/menu_item_divider_3"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="@string/item_4"
            android:clickable="true">
        </TextView> 
        <View
            android:id="@+id/menu_item_divider_4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/menu_item_4"
            android:background="#b5b5b5" />
         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/menu_item_5"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/menu_item_divider_4"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="@string/item_5"
            android:clickable="true">
        </TextView>
        <View
            android:id="@+id/menu_item_divider_5"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/menu_item_5"
            android:background="#b5b5b5" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/menu_item_6"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/menu_item_divider_5"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="@string/item_6"
            android:clickable="true">
        </TextView>
        <View
            android:id="@+id/menu_item_divider_6"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/menu_item_6"
            android:background="#b5b5b5" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/menu_item_7"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/menu_item_divider_6"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="@string/item_7"
            android:clickable="true">
        </TextView>
        <View
            android:id="@+id/menu_item_divider_7"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/menu_item_7"
            android:background="#b5b5b5" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/menu_item_8"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/menu_item_divider_7"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="@string/item_8"
            android:clickable="true">
        </TextView>  

        </RelativeLayout>

        </ScrollView> 


    </LinearLayout>


    <ScrollView 
       android:id="@+id/descriptionScrollView"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
       android:scrollbars="none">       

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="India ie. Bharat is a Union of States. " />

        </ScrollView>
```

After running the code the menutext1, menutext2 , ......,menutext8 OnClickListener of  these TextViews in slider is not executed !????!
pls help . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting your `TextView` as clickable.

```
textView.setClickable(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Introduction extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
ImageView menubutton;
TextView intro;
TextView menutext1;
TextView menutext2;
TextView menutext3;
TextView menutext4;
TextView menutext5;
TextView menutext6;
TextView menutext7;
TextView menutext8;
RelativeLayout menupanel;
ScrollView description;
Boolean move = false;
TextView tv1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.introduction);

    menubutton=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.menuViewButton);
    menutext1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.menu_item_1);
    menutext2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.menu_item_2);
    menutext3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.menu_item_3);
    menutext4=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.menu_item_4);
    menutext5=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.menu_item_5);
    menutext6=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.menu_item_6);
    menutext7=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.menu_item_7);
    menutext8=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.menu_item_8);
    menutext1.setOnClickListener(this);
    menupanel=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.menuPanel);
    description=(ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.descriptionScrollView);
    intro=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.intro);
        tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        menutext1.setOnClickListener(this);
        menutext2.setOnClickListener(this);
        menutext3.setOnClickListener(this);
        menutext4.setOnClickListener(this);
        menutext5.setOnClickListener(this);
        menutext6.setOnClickListener(this);
        menutext7.setOnClickListener(this);
        menutext8.setOnClickListener(this);

         }

             public void preface()
             {


            move = false;
            Animation slideright= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.right_to_left);
            Animation slide= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.movingright_to_left);
            menupanel.startAnimation(slideright);
            description.startAnimation(slide);
            intro.setText("Preface");
            Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Inside preface", 1);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL,0, 130);
            toast.show();

            tv1.setText("This is the third pocket size edition ");
         }

         @Override
         public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
      }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             switch (v.getid())
            {
            case R.id.menu_item_1:
                  move = false;
                         Animation slideright=              AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.right_to_left);
            Animation slide= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.movingright_to_left);
            menupanel.startAnimation(slideright);
            description.startAnimation(slide);
            intro.setText("Introduction");
    break;
    case R.id.menu_item_2:
       move = false;
            Animation slideright= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.right_to_left);
            Animation slide= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.movingright_to_left);
            menupanel.startAnimation(slideright);
            description.startAnimation(slide);
            intro.setText("Preface");
            Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Inside preface", 1);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL,0, 130);
            toast.show();

            tv1.setText("This is the third pocket size edition of the Constitution of India in the diglot form. In this edition, the text of the Constitution of India has been brought up-to-date by incorporating therein all the amendments up to and including the Constitution (Ninety-Sixth Amendment) Act, 2011.  \n\n 2. The Constitution applies to the State of Jammu and Kashmir with certain exceptions and modifications as provided in article 370 and the Constitution (Application to Jammu and Kashmir) Order, 1954. This Order has been included in Appendix I for facility of reference.  Appendix II contains a re-statement of the exceptions and modifications.  The text of the constitutional amendments relating to the Constitution (Forty-fourth Amendment) Act, 1978 and Constitution (Eighty-eighth Amendment) Act, 2003, which have not come in force, have been provided in Appendix  III and IV respectively. ");
    break;
    case R.id.menu_item_3:
      move = false;
            Animation slideright= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.right_to_left);
            Animation slide= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.movingright_to_left);
            menupanel.startAnimation(slideright);
            description.startAnimation(slide);
            intro.setText("Preamble");
    break;
    case R.id.menu_item_4:
    move = false;
            Animation slideright= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.right_to_left);
            Animation slide= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.movingright_to_left);
            menupanel.startAnimation(slideright);
            description.startAnimation(slide);
            intro.setText("Index");
    break;
    case R.id.menu_item_5:  
     move = false;
            Animation slideright= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.right_to_left);
            Animation slide= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.movingright_to_left);
            menupanel.startAnimation(slideright);
            description.startAnimation(slide);
            intro.setText("Articles");
    break;
    case  R.id.menu_item_6:
    move = false;
            Animation slideright= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.right_to_left);
            Animation slide= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.movingright_to_left);
            menupanel.startAnimation(slideright);
            description.startAnimation(slide);
            intro.setText("Schedules");
    break;
    case R.id.menu_item_7:
      move = false;
            Animation slideright= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.right_to_left);
            Animation slide= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.movingright_to_left);
            menupanel.startAnimation(slideright);
            description.startAnimation(slide);
            intro.setText("Appendix");
    break;
    case R.id.menu_item_8:
     move = false;
            Animation slideright= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.right_to_left);
            Animation slide= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.movingright_to_left);
            menupanel.startAnimation(slideright);
            description.startAnimation(slide);
            intro.setText("Amendment");
    break;
    case R.id.menubutton:
         if(!move)
    {
        move = true;

        Animation slideleft= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.move);
        Animation slide= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.moving);
        menupanel.startAnimation(slideleft);
    //  introduction.startAnimation(slide);
    }

       else{
           move = false;
          Animation slideright= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(),        R.anim.right_to_left);
          Animation slide= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(),   R.anim.movingright_to_left);
          menupanel.startAnimation(slideright);
          //introduction.startAnimation(slide);

        }
    }
    }

      }
```